# ¿Por que se redondean los decimales sin ninguna instrucción para ello en C?

Tags: c

El propósito del programa es resolver la suma de una sucesión de fracciones del tipo "n/2^n" pero desde el valor 26 todas las respuestas son "2.0000" no se si es el lenguaje o si estoy haciendo algo mal, intente usar "double" pero el resultado era el mismo.

```
       #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(){
    int numb=0;
    float limite,suma=0,fraccion,potencia;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("Este código resuelve la sumatoria de una sucesión de la forma\n");
    printf("---------------------------n/2^n---------------------------\n\n");
    while(1){
            
    printf("Coloca el valor de <n> \n");
    scanf("%f",&limite);
    if(limite<=0)
    break;
     do{
        potencia=(float)pow(2,++numb);
        fraccion+=(numb/potencia);
    }while(numb<limite);

    printf(" la respuesta es  : %f\n\n",fraccion);
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    numb=0;fraccion=0;

}
    
    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: @Christian Creo que comentarios como  *"una leída al libro"* están de más  en un sitio donde la gente viene a aprender y tras de todo donde OP hace un código válido que demuestra esfuerzo. ```fraccion += numb/(numb*numb)``` no serviría ya que es lo mismo que  ```fraccion += 1/numb``` y no hace lo que OP quiere. Si el problema es de redondeo por el ```int``` que tienes ahí (```numb```), luna opción sería castearlo como ```float``` en ```fraccion+=(numb/potencia);``` así: ```fraccion+=( (float)numb/potencia);```

Answer (score 0):

Es importante para la solución del problema el cast entre enteros y reales, cuando se realiza la división, puedes probar un programa como este:

```
#include 

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    float sum = 0.0;
    printf("Coloca el valor de n \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i=i+1){
            sum = sum + i/(float)(i*i);
    }
    printf("El valor del sumatorio de la sucesión es: %f\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```